# Is this a good way to have two UI between iPad and iPad mini?

Tags: ipad, screen-resolution

Yes, the iPad and iPad mini finally come with same resolutions. And the difference between two device is physical size. But the question I have is...Should I make the iPad have more view than the iPad mini?

Let say I am writing an application that shows a map. So, on the iPad mini, let's say, I show 100 km * 100 km place, it works nice, but for iPad, it seems that every thing will become bigger. Is this a good way to show more? For example, 120 km * 120 km (Scale is not correct in this example) in iPad. So, the scale of the map symbol is the same, but can see more things. Is this a good way to do this? Please share your view.

Answer (score 1):

"Do you have a different zoom level for a desktop view?"

If yes, you can continue the same rule on other resolutions. As far as I know, Google maps has zoom levels that can be combined with the screen resolution.